# How does app.DragAndDrop() work in a xamarin ui test

Tags: c#, xamarin.uitest

I have tiles that list accounts. I want to drag one onto the position of the other and have tried the below code but neither seems to work:

```
AppResult[] fro = app.Query(x => x.Id("reorder_icon").Sibling().Marked(fromAccount));
AppResult[] t = app.Query(x => x.Id("reorder_icon").Sibling().Marked(toAccount));

app.DragCoordinates(fro.FirstOrDefault().Rect.CenterX, fro.FirstOrDefault().Rect.CenterY, t.FirstOrDefault().Rect.CenterX, t.FirstOrDefault().Rect.CenterY);
app.DragAndDrop(x => x.Id("reorder_icon").Sibling().Marked(fromAccount),x => x.Id("reorder_icon").Sibling().Marked(toAccount));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to contact Xamarin to get this issue resolved. They have now added functionality to the DragAndDrop() method to ensure that behaviour described in question can be executed.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18725114)

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg - this is not additional information really, this is a (not a majorly good) answer.

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg the answer is that xamarin/microsoft had to add functionality for DragAndDrop() method to hold the co-ordinates of the item being selected before dragging it to required position. What do you suggest would be a better answer @CalvT븃?